# How Java 1.4 will connect with MQ 7.5?

Tags: ibm-mq

As per MQ 7.5 client, minimum requirement is jdk 1.5 client want to connect with MQ. But my application is written in jdk 1.4 and client don't want to migrate application from 1.4 to 1.5. they are upgrading MQ client from 7.0.0 to 7.5. Please suggest if we have any alternate solution for this.

Comment: Please define "solution" in this context. Do you consider it "solved" if it can be made to run but IBM won't support it if it breaks?

Comment: Without migrating application to Java 1.5, I don't see a way out here.

Comment: Also, the choice to use v7.5 seems odd.  It is End of Service in 16 months.  Why not use v8.0 or v9.0 for which no EOS date has yet been announced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a question about managing software upgrades.

Is it possible the client is moving to WMQ 7.5 because 7.0 has reached end of support?

In that case the same business case can be made for JRE 1.4 end of support:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html

Comment: Thanks Stavr00, Yes 7.0 support is over and client is moving to 7.5 but not sure old java 1.4 will be able to connect MQ 7.5 or not.

Answer (score 1):

JDK/JRE v1.4.2 has been long out of support by Oracle/Sun.  Use a supported version of the JDK/JRE by Oracle.

IBM has an easy to use web page to look up MQ version and the minimum supported version of Java (JDK/JRE).  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27006467

Summary:

- MQ v7.0.0/7.0.1 supports JDK/JRE 32-bit v1.4.2 or higher / 64-bit v5.0 or higher
- MQ v7.1 supports JDK/JRE 32-bit & 64-bit v5.0 or higher
- MQ v7.5 supports JDK/JRE 32-bit & 64-bit v5.0 or higher
- MQ v8.0 supports JDK/JRE 32-bit & 64-bit v7.0 or higher
- MQ v9.0 supports JDK/JRE 32-bit & 64-bit v7.0 or higher